# Recursive Method in Java, Invalid AssignmentOperator

Tags: java, eclipse, recursion, methods

I am trying to use a recursive method in Java for an assignment in my class. We were given what to return for each condition, and what to use to test the method.

However, it keeps telling me that the (r-1) and (p-1), within the if/else statements in the method, have an invalid AssignmentOperator.

I have tried changing the return types on the method, messed around with the structure of the statements, and so on..

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        recursiveAlgorithm(0, 0);
        recursiveAlgorithm(0, 1);
        recursiveAlgorithm(1, 1);
        recursiveAlgorithm(1, 2); 
        recursiveAlgorithm(1, 3);
        recursiveAlgorithm(2, 2);
        recursiveAlgorithm(3, 2);


}

     public static int recursiveAlgorithm(int r, int p) {

        if (r == 0) {
            return p + 1;
        }

        if (p == 0){
            return recursiveAlgorithm(r – 1, 1);
        }

        else {
            return recursiveAlgorithm(r – 1, recursiveAlgorithm(r, p – 1));
        }

    }
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, I'm sure it has something to do with my syntax, but I have no idea what else to try. Any help would be very, very much appreciated.

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
Syntax error on token "Invalid Character", invalid AssignmentOperator
Syntax error on token "Invalid Character", invalid AssignmentOperator
Syntax error on token "Invalid Character", invalid AssignmentOperator

at javaproject.Java_Recursion.recursiveAlgorithm(Java_Recursion.java:25)
at morris_brittany.Java_Recursion.main(Java_Recursion.java:7)
```

Comment: can you show your actual error stack trace?

Comment: What line is the error on and what is the `csc2650Algorithm` method?

Comment: Sorry, I had forgotten to change the name within the method when I posted it. The only method is the recursiveAlgorithm one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    recursiveAlgorithm(0, 0);
    recursiveAlgorithm(0, 1);
    recursiveAlgorithm(1, 1);
    recursiveAlgorithm(1, 2); 
    recursiveAlgorithm(1, 3);
    recursiveAlgorithm(2, 2);
    recursiveAlgorithm(3, 2);
```

}

```
 public static int recursiveAlgorithm(int r, int p) {

    if (r == 0) {
        return p + 1;
    }

    if (p == 0){
        return recursiveAlgorithm(r - 1, 1);
    }

    else {
        return recursiveAlgorithm(r - 1, recursiveAlgorithm(r, p - 1));
    }

}
```

The problem was your `-` was a different character than the minus sign on your keyboard.  I have no idea why you put that kind of character there, but my eclipse said the character was not a `-`
You can use [this](https://mothereff.in/binary-ascii) and see copy this `-` and `–` to see that they are both truly different.

Answer (score 0):

You need the '-' character, not the '–' character. Somehow, your code contains a unicode minus (three of them, actually...most likely a copy-paste error). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen-minus.